# power bi dax sum up all entries matching endofmonth filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I have a data table in powerbi structured

```
 id     date           data
 1     2022-10-31      123
 1     2022-11-30      456
 1     2022-12-01      789
```

the data spans multiple user ids and multiple years. This is not the real data

I want to  define a measure to sum up all end of month values and only end of month values. If I fed this data, the measure would return 579 (123+456). Also I will use slicers on user ID's in case that changes the DAX

This is the best thing I have so far

```
Measure = 
SUMX(
    CALCULATETABLE(
        'Table', ENDOFMONTH('Table'[Dates]) 
    ),
    'Table'[data]
    )
```

Basically create a table2 containing only endofmonth records of main table and sum up the data in table2.

This only returns the last value (as you can see, the values add up every day) so 789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use simply:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE(
    SUM( 'Table'[data] ),
    'Table'[date] = EOMONTH( 'Table'[date], 0 )
)
```

***Edit**: as per your new requirement*:

```
Measure =
VAR T1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        'Table',
        "Last Date in Month",
            CALCULATE(
                MAX( 'Table'[date] ),
                FILTER(
                    'Table',
                    MONTH( 'Table'[date] ) = MONTH( EARLIER( 'Table'[date] ) )
                        && YEAR( 'Table'[date] ) = YEAR( EARLIER( 'Table'[date] ) )
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX( T1, IF( 'Table'[date] = [Last Date in Month], 'Table'[data] ) )
```

Comment: hi jos, this works thanks. Small followup, I noticed some users had incomplete records, for instance this one has nothing on july 30 and sept 30 https://imgur.com/XORxyL5 . The measure thus returns 295 instead of the expected 503. Table visualisation seems able to do the month breakdown. How to replicate this in dax? the result should be the sum of all rows

Comment: Hi @rubhemaju. Not sure I understand your new request. The total of 295 is correct, no? Your original spec was for "*a measure to sum up all end of month values and **only** end of month values*".

Comment: hi yes but i didnt realize my dataset would be incomplete (rookie mistake sorry). if actual end of month is missing, I'd like to take the next best thing (which is what table visual in powerbi seems to do). Is this possible?

Comment: What's the "next best thing"? The latest date for that month?

Comment: yes......................................

Comment: Have added a new solution.